# Unable to pick date from bootstrap calendar in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, bootstrap-datepicker

It will show the enabled dates from `tomorrow to end date of the month`. I gave date in excel sheet and write this code to pick date.

`row.click()` is clicking on today's date. While I gave If condition so it should work when date will equal to my given argument "day"

```
List<WebElement> tableRows = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='datetimepicker datetimepicker-dropdown-bottom-right dropdown-menu'][1]//div[@class='datetimepicker-days']//table//tbody//tr//td[@class='day']"));
for (WebElement row : tableRows) 
{
    String actualDay = row.getText();
    if (actualDay.equals(day)) 
    {
        row.click();
    }
}
```

Comment: can you share the html sippet of the element you are trying to click, your xpath is way too long. and why loop, why not just find an unique xpath?

Comment: I am using data provider to enter date. So date can be different in every case.

Comment: it still doesn't answer my question. data provider has nothing to do with long xpath and loops.